# How to make responsive text appear inside a SVG (map & country name)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I've been trying to search for solutions out there, but it seems impossible for a newbie like me!
For further info: I have a SVG world map, which is responsive when it comes to its width. I've been able to implement a toggle that works, but now I want it to toggle on and off the screen the different country names on the map.

The problem then is that I do not know how to approach this, as the text should be responsive too and visually appear on the screen while the toggle is on.

I would show you my code but all I have is the toggle and the svg image. You can check it out on the github repo: https://github.com/Swilkery/Risk/pull/8

Could you tell me what to use? I've seen some people using  but I do not know where to place it inside each path: (This is an example path that is the US)

````
<path class="st1" d="M187.4,67.6l-2.1,0.7l-1.6,0.9l-1.6,0.9l-0.2,0.3l2-0.5l0.7,0.7l1.6-0.5l1.7-0.7l1.9-0.7l-1.1,1.1l0.9,0.3
       l0.9,0.8l1.8-0.5l1.8-0.2l0.1,0.6l0.5,0.1L195,71l0.5,0.9l-1.6,0.2l0,0l-1.3-0.2l-1.6,0.4l-1.3,0.2l-1.6,1.4l-1,0.8l0.1,0.2l1.9-1.4
       h0.2l-1.6,1.7l-1,1.5l-0.9,1.3l-0.2,1.1l-0.3,0.5l-0.2,0.6v1.1l0.1,0.2h0.6l0.6-0.2L187,81l1.1-1.1l0.6-1.5V77l0.5-0.9l0.9-1.1
       l0.7-0.8l0.9-0.5l-0.1,0.7l0.8-1.1l0.5-0.2l0.6-0.8l1.3,0.5l1,0.8l-0.3,1l-0.6,1l-1.3,0.9l-0.1,0.6h0.3l1.5-0.9l0.6,0.2l-0.2,1.3
       l-0.2,0.9l-1.3,1.2l-0.7,0.8l-0.9,0.8l0.9,0.5l0.9,0.1l1.4-0.3l1.3-0.6l1-0.3l1.6-0.6l2-1.3v-0.2l0.1-0.7l0.9-0.3l1.4,0.1l1.4,0.2
       l1.6-0.7l0.2-0.9l-0.1-0.3l2.4-1.5l0.9-0.4h2.7h3.2l0.4-0.5l0.6-0.1l0.9-0.3l1-1l1.1-1.7l1.9-1.6l0.4,0.6l1.3-0.3l0.6,0.6l-1,3
       l0.8,1.3l0.1,0.7l-2.2,1l-2.1,0.8l-2.1,0.7l-1.4,1.3l-0.5,0.5l-0.4,1.2l0.2,1.1l0.7,0.1l0.1-0.8l0.4,0.5l-0.3,0.6l-1.3,0.3h-0.9
       l-1.5,0.4l-0.8,0.1l-1.1,0.1l-1.7,0.7l2.8-0.4l0.4,0.4l-2.7,0.7H209l0.1-0.3l-0.7,0.6l0.5,0.1l-0.9,1.6l-1.8,1.7v-0.6l-0.4-0.1
       l-0.4-0.6v1.2l0.3,0.4l-0.2,0.8l-0.8,0.9l-1.6,1.8l-0.1-0.1l1-1.5l-0.7-0.8l0.3-1.9l-0.7,1v1.4l-1.1-0.3l1,0.7l-0.5,2.1l0.5,0.2v0.8
       l-0.3,2.2l-1.6,1.6l-2.1,0.7l-1.5,1.3l-1,0.1l-1.2,0.8l-0.5,0.7l-2.4,1.5l-1.3,1.1l-1.2,1.3l-0.7,1.6v1.6l0.2,1.9l0.5,1.6l-0.2,1
       l0.5,2.6l-0.3,1.5l-0.2,0.9l-0.7,1.4l-0.6,0.3l-0.9-0.3l-0.1-1l-0.6-0.5l-0.7-1.9l-0.6-1.7l-0.1-0.9l0.7-1.5l-0.3-1.2l-1.1-1.9
       l-0.7-0.3l-2.1,1l-0.3-0.1l-0.7-1l-1-0.6l-2.2,0.3l-1.6-0.3l-1.5,0.2l-0.9,0.3l0.2,0.6l-0.2,0.9l0.3,0.5l-0.4,0.3l-0.6-0.3L172,110
       l-1.4-0.1l-1.1-1.2l-1.7,0.3l-1.3-0.5l-1.2,0.2l-1.7,0.5l-2.1,1.6l-2.1,1l-1.3,1l-0.7,1l-0.3,1.6l-0.1,1l0.2,0.8l-0.8,0.1l-1.3-0.5
       l-1.4-0.7l-0.3-1l-0.1-1.6l-0.8-1.3l-0.3-1.3l-0.6-1.5l-1.1-0.9l-1.6,0.1l-1.7,1.7l-1.4-0.7l-0.8-0.7l-0.1-1.3l-0.3-1.1l-0.8-1
       l-0.7-0.7l-0.5-0.8h-3.3l-0.3,0.9h-1.5h-3.8l-3.8-1.6l-2.4-1.1l0.3-0.5l-2.5,0.2l-2.2,0.2l0.1-1.1l-0.7-1.3l-0.8-0.3v-0.6l-1-0.1
       l-0.4-0.6l-1.7-0.2l-0.3-0.4l0.3-1.2l-0.9-2.2l-0.2-3.1l0.3-0.5l-0.5-0.7l-0.5-1.9l0.6-1.8l-0.3-1.2l1.4-1.8l1-1.9l0.4-1.7l1.9-2.1
       l1.4-2l1.4-2l1.5-3l0.6-1.8l0.1-1l0.5-0.5l2,0.8l-0.3,2l0.8-0.6l0.9-1.8l0.6-1.8h4.9h5.1h1.7h5.2h5.1h5.1h5.2h5.8h5.9h3.5l0.5-0.8
       h0.6l-0.3,1.2l0.3,0.3l1.1,0.1l1.6,0.3l1.4,0.7l1.5-0.3L187.4,67.6z M95.5,48.1l-2.4,0.8l-0.3-0.6l0.8-1l2.2-0.7l1.2-0.3l0.9,0.1
       v0.7L95.5,48.1z M82,42.4l-1.4,0.3L80,42.3l-0.3-0.6l2-0.3l1,0.2L82,42.4z M82.4,34.6l0.4,0.3l1.2-0.2l0.6,0.5l1.1,0.2l-0.4,0.2
       L83.6,36L83,35.7l-0.1-0.3l-1.5,0.1l-0.1-0.2L82.4,34.6z M142.4,23.1l-8.5,7.1l-12.4,11.4l1.5,0.1l1,0.6l0.2,0.9l0.1,1.3l2.6-1.1
       l2.3-0.7l-0.2,1.1l0.3,0.8l0.6,0.9l-0.4,1.5l-0.5,2.4l1.6,1.3l-1.1,1.3l-1.8,1l-0.2-0.8l-0.9-0.7l1.1-1.8l-0.6-1.7l0.9-1.9l-1.4-0.1
       h-2.5l-1.3-0.6l-1.1-2.1l-1.1-0.4l-2-0.7l-2.4,0.2l-2.1-0.9l-0.9-0.9L111,41l-1.2,1.4l-1,0.1l-2.3,0.4l-2.2,0.7l-2.2,0.5l1.1-1.2
       l2.9-2l2.4-0.6l0.1-0.5l-3.3,1.1l-2.6,1.4l-3.9,1.5l0.1,1L95.8,46l-2.7,0.9l-2.3,0.7l-1.4,0.9l-3.7,1.1l-1.6,1l-2.8,0.9l-0.9-0.1
       L78.2,52l-2.4,0.7l-2.1,0.7L70.2,54l0.1-0.4l2.8-1l2.3-0.7l3-1.1l2.3-0.2l1.7-0.9l3.6-1.3l0.8-0.4l2-0.7l2-1.6l2.2-1.2l-2.5,0.6
       l-0.1-0.4l-1.7,0.8l0.1-1l-1.3,0.7l0.6-1L85.6,45h-1l1.3-1.2L87,43l0-0.8l-2.5,0.4l-0.2-1l-0.5-0.5l1.4-1.1l-0.1-0.9l2-1.1l2.7-1.1
       l1.8-1l1.4-0.1l0.6,0.3l2.5-1l0.9,0.2l1.9-0.6l0.9-0.9l-0.4-0.3l2.1-0.8h-1L98.4,33l-1,0.5L96.8,33l-2.4,0.2l-1.6-0.5l0.4-0.8
       l-0.3-1.1l3.2-0.8l4.6-0.9h1.2l-1.5,1l3.2-0.1l0.4-1.2l-0.8-0.7l0.3-1l-0.2-0.8l-1.1-0.6l2.3-1l2.6-0.1l3.1-0.8l1.7-0.9l2.7-0.9
       l1.7-0.2l3.9-0.8l1.1,0.1l3.6-1l1.5,0.4l-0.2,0.8l1.1-0.3l2.2,0.1l-0.7,0.4l1.7,0.3l1.7-0.2l2.2,0.6l2.5,0.2l0.8,0.2l2.3-0.3
       l1.4,0.6L142.4,23.1z"/> 
<desc>US</desc> ```
````

Comment: 1. in order to make an svg element responsive you need to use an viewBox attribute and no width or height. in this case the svg element will take all the width available. 2. if you need to add some text you need to put the text inside a `<text>` element. 3. The <defs> element is used to store graphical objects that will be used at a later time. Objects created inside a <defs> element are not rendered

Comment: @enxaneta thanks for your answer. SVG is now responsive. You talk about adding text with <text>, where should I place it so that it responsively adapts to the region? If you could provide me with the example above that would be great. I y get the use of <defs> as you name them. Looking forward to your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
<path inkscape:connector-curvature="0" id="AW" data-name="Aruba" data-id="AW"
                                d="m 586.6,492.9 -0.1,-0.1 -0.3,-0.6 -0.3,-0.3 -0.1,0.1 -0.1,0.3 0.3,0.3 0.3,0.4 0.3,0.1 0,-0.2 z"
                                data-info="<desc>US</desc>" />
```

using jquery to catch the onclick country and display the data-info of that particular country.

```
$(document).click(function(event){
if(event.target.id=="Aruba"){
  alert($('#AW').data('info'));
}
});
```

Comment: Would it be possible to code that same jQuery with JS? Could you help me out with that?

Comment: There is no need to use Javascript for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As I've commented:

1. in order to make an svg element responsive you need to use an viewBox attribute and no width or height. in this case the svg element will take all the width available.
2. if you need to add some text you need to put the text inside a `<text>` element.
3. The `<defs>` element is used to store graphical objects that will be used at a later time. Objects created inside a  element are not rendered

This is an example where I've added 2 text elements. The x and y attributes are setting the position of the text.

```css
svg{fill:gold;}

text{dominant-baseline:central;
text-anchor:middle;
fill:black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="70 20 155 100">
  <path id="us" d="M187.4,67.6l-2.1,0.7l-1.6,0.9l-1.6,0.9l-0.2,0.3l2-0.5l0.7,0.7l1.6-0.5l1.7-0.7l1.9-0.7l-1.1,1.1l0.9,0.3
       l0.9,0.8l1.8-0.5l1.8-0.2l0.1,0.6l0.5,0.1L195,71l0.5,0.9l-1.6,0.2l0,0l-1.3-0.2l-1.6,0.4l-1.3,0.2l-1.6,1.4l-1,0.8l0.1,0.2l1.9-1.4
       h0.2l-1.6,1.7l-1,1.5l-0.9,1.3l-0.2,1.1l-0.3,0.5l-0.2,0.6v1.1l0.1,0.2h0.6l0.6-0.2L187,81l1.1-1.1l0.6-1.5V77l0.5-0.9l0.9-1.1
       l0.7-0.8l0.9-0.5l-0.1,0.7l0.8-1.1l0.5-0.2l0.6-0.8l1.3,0.5l1,0.8l-0.3,1l-0.6,1l-1.3,0.9l-0.1,0.6h0.3l1.5-0.9l0.6,0.2l-0.2,1.3
       l-0.2,0.9l-1.3,1.2l-0.7,0.8l-0.9,0.8l0.9,0.5l0.9,0.1l1.4-0.3l1.3-0.6l1-0.3l1.6-0.6l2-1.3v-0.2l0.1-0.7l0.9-0.3l1.4,0.1l1.4,0.2
       l1.6-0.7l0.2-0.9l-0.1-0.3l2.4-1.5l0.9-0.4h2.7h3.2l0.4-0.5l0.6-0.1l0.9-0.3l1-1l1.1-1.7l1.9-1.6l0.4,0.6l1.3-0.3l0.6,0.6l-1,3
       l0.8,1.3l0.1,0.7l-2.2,1l-2.1,0.8l-2.1,0.7l-1.4,1.3l-0.5,0.5l-0.4,1.2l0.2,1.1l0.7,0.1l0.1-0.8l0.4,0.5l-0.3,0.6l-1.3,0.3h-0.9
       l-1.5,0.4l-0.8,0.1l-1.1,0.1l-1.7,0.7l2.8-0.4l0.4,0.4l-2.7,0.7H209l0.1-0.3l-0.7,0.6l0.5,0.1l-0.9,1.6l-1.8,1.7v-0.6l-0.4-0.1
       l-0.4-0.6v1.2l0.3,0.4l-0.2,0.8l-0.8,0.9l-1.6,1.8l-0.1-0.1l1-1.5l-0.7-0.8l0.3-1.9l-0.7,1v1.4l-1.1-0.3l1,0.7l-0.5,2.1l0.5,0.2v0.8
       l-0.3,2.2l-1.6,1.6l-2.1,0.7l-1.5,1.3l-1,0.1l-1.2,0.8l-0.5,0.7l-2.4,1.5l-1.3,1.1l-1.2,1.3l-0.7,1.6v1.6l0.2,1.9l0.5,1.6l-0.2,1
       l0.5,2.6l-0.3,1.5l-0.2,0.9l-0.7,1.4l-0.6,0.3l-0.9-0.3l-0.1-1l-0.6-0.5l-0.7-1.9l-0.6-1.7l-0.1-0.9l0.7-1.5l-0.3-1.2l-1.1-1.9
       l-0.7-0.3l-2.1,1l-0.3-0.1l-0.7-1l-1-0.6l-2.2,0.3l-1.6-0.3l-1.5,0.2l-0.9,0.3l0.2,0.6l-0.2,0.9l0.3,0.5l-0.4,0.3l-0.6-0.3L172,110
       l-1.4-0.1l-1.1-1.2l-1.7,0.3l-1.3-0.5l-1.2,0.2l-1.7,0.5l-2.1,1.6l-2.1,1l-1.3,1l-0.7,1l-0.3,1.6l-0.1,1l0.2,0.8l-0.8,0.1l-1.3-0.5
       l-1.4-0.7l-0.3-1l-0.1-1.6l-0.8-1.3l-0.3-1.3l-0.6-1.5l-1.1-0.9l-1.6,0.1l-1.7,1.7l-1.4-0.7l-0.8-0.7l-0.1-1.3l-0.3-1.1l-0.8-1
       l-0.7-0.7l-0.5-0.8h-3.3l-0.3,0.9h-1.5h-3.8l-3.8-1.6l-2.4-1.1l0.3-0.5l-2.5,0.2l-2.2,0.2l0.1-1.1l-0.7-1.3l-0.8-0.3v-0.6l-1-0.1
       l-0.4-0.6l-1.7-0.2l-0.3-0.4l0.3-1.2l-0.9-2.2l-0.2-3.1l0.3-0.5l-0.5-0.7l-0.5-1.9l0.6-1.8l-0.3-1.2l1.4-1.8l1-1.9l0.4-1.7l1.9-2.1
       l1.4-2l1.4-2l1.5-3l0.6-1.8l0.1-1l0.5-0.5l2,0.8l-0.3,2l0.8-0.6l0.9-1.8l0.6-1.8h4.9h5.1h1.7h5.2h5.1h5.1h5.2h5.8h5.9h3.5l0.5-0.8
       h0.6l-0.3,1.2l0.3,0.3l1.1,0.1l1.6,0.3l1.4,0.7l1.5-0.3L187.4,67.6z
       M95.5,48.1l-2.4,0.8l-0.3-0.6l0.8-1l2.2-0.7l1.2-0.3l0.9,0.1
       v0.7L95.5,48.1z M82,42.4l-1.4,0.3L80,42.3l-0.3-0.6l2-0.3l1,0.2L82,42.4z M82.4,34.6l0.4,0.3l1.2-0.2l0.6,0.5l1.1,0.2l-0.4,0.2
       L83.6,36L83,35.7l-0.1-0.3l-1.5,0.1l-0.1-0.2L82.4,34.6z M142.4,23.1l-8.5,7.1l-12.4,11.4l1.5,0.1l1,0.6l0.2,0.9l0.1,1.3l2.6-1.1
       l2.3-0.7l-0.2,1.1l0.3,0.8l0.6,0.9l-0.4,1.5l-0.5,2.4l1.6,1.3l-1.1,1.3l-1.8,1l-0.2-0.8l-0.9-0.7l1.1-1.8l-0.6-1.7l0.9-1.9l-1.4-0.1
       h-2.5l-1.3-0.6l-1.1-2.1l-1.1-0.4l-2-0.7l-2.4,0.2l-2.1-0.9l-0.9-0.9L111,41l-1.2,1.4l-1,0.1l-2.3,0.4l-2.2,0.7l-2.2,0.5l1.1-1.2
       l2.9-2l2.4-0.6l0.1-0.5l-3.3,1.1l-2.6,1.4l-3.9,1.5l0.1,1L95.8,46l-2.7,0.9l-2.3,0.7l-1.4,0.9l-3.7,1.1l-1.6,1l-2.8,0.9l-0.9-0.1
       L78.2,52l-2.4,0.7l-2.1,0.7L70.2,54l0.1-0.4l2.8-1l2.3-0.7l3-1.1l2.3-0.2l1.7-0.9l3.6-1.3l0.8-0.4l2-0.7l2-1.6l2.2-1.2l-2.5,0.6
       l-0.1-0.4l-1.7,0.8l0.1-1l-1.3,0.7l0.6-1L85.6,45h-1l1.3-1.2L87,43l0-0.8l-2.5,0.4l-0.2-1l-0.5-0.5l1.4-1.1l-0.1-0.9l2-1.1l2.7-1.1
       l1.8-1l1.4-0.1l0.6,0.3l2.5-1l0.9,0.2l1.9-0.6l0.9-0.9l-0.4-0.3l2.1-0.8h-1L98.4,33l-1,0.5L96.8,33l-2.4,0.2l-1.6-0.5l0.4-0.8
       l-0.3-1.1l3.2-0.8l4.6-0.9h1.2l-1.5,1l3.2-0.1l0.4-1.2l-0.8-0.7l0.3-1l-0.2-0.8l-1.1-0.6l2.3-1l2.6-0.1l3.1-0.8l1.7-0.9l2.7-0.9
       l1.7-0.2l3.9-0.8l1.1,0.1l3.6-1l1.5,0.4l-0.2,0.8l1.1-0.3l2.2,0.1l-0.7,0.4l1.7,0.3l1.7-0.2l2.2,0.6l2.5,0.2l0.8,0.2l2.3-0.3
       l1.4,0.6L142.4,23.1z"/>
  <text id="text_al" x="115" y="32">AL</text>
  <text id="text_us" x="160" y="90">US</text>
</svg>
```

Please read about the [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) element in SVG.

Also please read about the [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute

Comment: That seems like something worth trying. Will check it out. As for the text, where do you know get the coordinates from? If let’s say the text is placed on the middle of the country, will the size automatically resize when the country’s area reduces cause of the screen size? Thanks!

Comment: Edit the map in a vector editor (like Inkscape) and add all the country names in.  If the text is in the SVG, it will scale up or down along with all the other elements in the SVG.  You can show and hide the country names by using CSS. For example `svg.hide-names text { display: none; }`.  Then to control the visibility of the names, just add or remove the class `"hide-names"` from the `<svg>` element.